# Laravel authenticate always fails without default user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-9

I'm doing something wrong?

**My `If (Auth::attempt($validated)) {}` always fails when I change default user. But work with default user. Maybe i forgot any config in my new user 'personal'?**

config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Personal::class,
        ],
```

App/Models/Personal.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Personal extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'personals';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

App\Http\Requests\AuthRequest.php

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AuthRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

App\Http\Controller\AuthController.php

```
public function login(AuthRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        if ($validated) {
            \Log::info($validated); //<- so far it works
            if (Auth::attempt($validated)) { //<- this if always fails with personal model, but it work with default user model
                \Log::info('test');
                $personal = Auth::user();
                
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['algo deu errado']);
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['Preencha todos os campos']);
    }
```

`$validated = [ 'email' => 'teste@outlook.com', 'password' => 'teste123', ];`

Comment: Have you also registered a guard for it? Also you should set that guard for that, otherwise it will take the default

Comment: No, I'am using default guard. I just changed the model in providers.

Comment: Change provider name to `personals`. And as @workservice said you should change `guard` as well to avoid using default.

Comment: try to clear:config or clear:cache or config:cache

Comment: I changed default guards and name providers, but still don`t work :(

Comment: i tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` but still not solved